# IP Addressing for Networking Devices - Clarifications

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ip-address

The textbook I'm using says that when setting up a network, an ISP assigns a public IP address to my router, and following that, the router then assigns the computers on my network their own, private IP addresses. That much, I do get.

However, it seems that the commonly used IP address 192.168.1.1 is used to refer to the router itself (more specifically, my modem's interface?) Is that the correct interpretation? If so, how exactly does that work? Wouldn't one use the IP assigned by the ISP? If I wanted to access my own router's interface rather than my modem, how might I go about it?

Comment: The public IP address is assigned to the router's port for the WAN side.  A private IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.1) is assigned to the router's port for the LAN side.  Since your PCs are on the LAN side of the router, you would access the router by using the IP address of the LAN (and not the WAN side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A router's job is to route traffic between networks.
In your case, there are indeed two different networks:  the Wide Area Network (WAN) and the Local Area Network (LAN). The WAN is your ISP's network; the LAN is your personal network. The router sits between these two networks—conceptually and physically.  Its job is to transport traffic from one network to the other, and vice versa.

To do this, the router has two different addresses, not just one.  It has a LAN address, which is (often) the 192.168.1.1 address you reference.  It also has a WAN address, the (usually) public address assigned to it by your ISP.

From inside your network, you can probably reach your router on either of its addresses, though ordinarily from the LAN side you would access it via its LAN address.  From outside your network, you can only reach your router via its WAN address—the LAN address, 192.168.1.1, is not routable *on the internet* which is why anyone's local LAN is free to use it without fear of conflicting with someone else.  The router does some magic, called Network Address Translation (or NAT), to make your local machines' outbound traffic appear to be coming from itself, so that only its public address is visible to the Internet. When reply traffic comes in, it reverses the NAT to send that reply traffic to whichever of your local machines was expecting it.

Hopefully that clears it up a little for you.